# Installing a new OpenBSD kernel "safely": why does `make install` go through these extra hoops?

Tags: filesystems, kernel, cp, openbsd, ffs

After building a new OpenBSD kernel, the `install` target of the kernel `Makefile` does the following:

```
rm -f /obsd
ln /bsd /obsd
cp bsd /nbsd
mv /nbsd /bsd
```

I understand that the first two lines remove the old backup kernel `/obsd` and create a hard link `/obsd` pointing to the currently running kernel `/bsd`. In particular, the running kernel is not moved at all. This makes sense to me.

However, what is the purpose of moving the newly built kernel `./bsd` first to `/nbsd` and then renaming it to `/bsd`? Why not replace the third and fourth line by the apparently simpler `cp bsd /bsd`?

If this should matter: the default partitioning scheme of OpenBSD places the kernel build tree in a different filesystem (disklabel) than the root filesystem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A makefile recipe will stop executing if any command in it returns a failure status (unless the command is preceded by a `-`). The recipe you cited will ensure that `/bsd` only gets replaced if the `cp bsd /nbsd` command succeeds. The cp could fail if the partition were full or out of inodes.